# Counting instances in a variable, then reformatting rows/columns within bash script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

Within a Batch submission script I have a file generated called "nodefile.123" that looks like:

> bear-pg0208u33b
>
> bear-pg0208u33b
>
> bear-pg0208u33b
>
> bear-pg0210u19a
>
> bear-pg0210u19a
>
> bear-pg0210u07a

It always has 1 entry per line, this is the location of each core that my program is to run on so there are 3 cores on -33b and and 2 cores on -19a and 1 core on -07a. I need to count the number of cores per node and format the data like this:

> bear-pg0208u33b:3:bear-pg0210u19a:2:bear-pg0210u07a:1

So far I have the following code:

> sort nodefile.3314190 | uniq -c > sorted.txt
>
> rev="$(awk '{for(i=NF;i>=1;i--) printf "%s ", $i;print ""}' sorted.txt)"

Which has counted and reversed the inputs. I believe I just now need to turn them into one line and change the space to a colon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `awk` :

```
awk 'BEGIN{c=1;OFS=":";ORS=":"} {if(u!=$0 && u!=""){print u,c;u=$0;c=1} else if(u!=$0){u=$0}else{c=c+1}} END{ORS="";print u,c;}' file
```

And your file should not have empty lines so you can remove them like:

```
sed -i '/^$/d' file
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I had just figured it out in am much more convoluted way, but had an unwanted ":" at the end of my script:

sort nodefile.3314190 | uniq -c > sorted.txt
awk '{for(i=NF;i>=1;i--) printf "%s ", $i;print ""}' sorted.txt > rev.txt
awk 'BEGIN { ORS = " " } { print }' rev.txt > conv.txt
sed -e 's/\s\+/:/g' conv.txt > machines.txt